# How can I add a HTML Button which executes a PHP file

Tags: php, html

I need an HTML button which executes and retrieves the value of this URI:

```
https://example.org/qrcodes/qrcode.php?user=
```

However, I am new in PHP and don't know how to handle that.

The PHP file, `grcode.php` contains this:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
$user = 'https://example.org/mitglieder/' . $_GET['user']. '';
$username = $_GET['user']; 


$qrcode = new Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
$qrcode->setText($user);
$qrcode->setSize(400);
$qrcode->setForegroundColor(['r' => 33, 'g' => 117, 'b' => 194, 'a' => 0]);
$qrcode->setBackgroundColor(['r' => 254, 'g' => 203, 'b' => 96, 'a' => 0]);
$qrcode->setLabel($username, 10);

$qrcode->writeFile($username.'.png');
echo $qrcode->writeString();
```

Comment: Does that code not just create a QR code? In which case, wouldn't you just embed it into the HTML with a normal `<img ... />` tag? Something like `<img src="https://example.org/qrcodes/qrcode.php?user=<?= $loginname; ?>" ... />`

Comment: i want to add a button under the normal profil picture which change it into a qrcode but i dont know how i can add a button which run the php script to create the qrcode

Comment: you will have to learn javascript in order todo so

Comment: You should include both the qr code and the normal image in the html and than use javascript to switch between the two. Just hide the qr-code with a display:none; and use a jquery show() and hide() to switch between the two

Comment: he could also make a `<button>` which will change the SRC of the profile image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using JQuery. First, add a button:

```
<button type="button" id="qr-btn">View QR Code</button>
```

Then, add a click listener to the button that sends a `GET` request to the PHP file which gets the response of `echo $qrcode->writeString();`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#qr-btn').click(function() {
            $.get('qrcode.php', { user: 'currentUserName' })
                .done(function(response) {
                    // TODO: update the IMG src to the response data
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I suggest you do not send the (string) value of the username, and instead send the (int) ID of that user then do a database query to get the (string) value of the username to prevent any future security flaws.

---

To update an `<img src=` of this example:

```
<img src="blank.png" id="profile-img">
```

You can do:

```
$('#profile-img').attr("src", response);
```

---

**However, you should:**

This will use a lot of resources on your server, since for each and every time the button is clicked, you're creating a new QR code. Potentially think about creating these on account creation and storing the image path inside the database to the QR code rather than someone write some Javascript to potentially use all of your server memory.

You're doing this here:

```
$qrcode->writeFile($username.'.png');
```